# Ajax pagination and remembering last page

Tags: ajax, caching, yii, history

I have ajax pagination:

```
class AjaxPager extends CLinkPager {

     protected function createPageButton($label,$page,$class,$hidden,$selected)
     {
                if($hidden || $selected)
                        $class.=' '.($hidden ? $this->hiddenPageCssClass : $this->selectedPageCssClass);
                return '<li class="'.$class.'">'.CHtml::ajaxLink($label,$this->createPageUrl($page), array(
                    'update'=>'#auctionList', 
                    'data' => array('price_from'=>$_GET['price_from'],'price_to'=>$_GET['price_to']) 
                    ), array('id'=>'link-'.uniqid())).'</li>';
    }

}
```

When i am on second page, click to view item details and go back, then i am on first page. I know i must use history.pushState but I don't know how use it in AjaxPager. Can you help me?

**Edit:**
I add `'complete' => 'function(){ window.history.pushState({}, "", this.url); }',` but when I use back button it loads only ajax content from cache, instead of layout with it. How to prevent this?